# how to estimate the coefficients of two margins by copula?

Tags: r, copula

I am trying to fit a copula for two categorical variables(each variable in 4 categories) I=4 and J=4
[image]
[image]

If I plug margins and copula function into log likelihood, and apply optim, I can estimate the coefficients of margins, β1,β2,β3,γ1,γ2,γ3 and also copula parameter(theta).

But I want to do it with "copula" package in R, but don't know what exactly should I write? I get this error

```
"Error in lm.fit(X, y = itau) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'"
```

help please
This is my piece of code:

```
#### F(x), betas are the parameters to be estimated
Fmarginal <- function(betas){
N <- 4617 ## no of observations
I <- 4 ## no of vehicle type choices
B1<-betas[1:4]
B2<-betas[5:8]
B0<-betas[9:12]
x1<-dist
x2<-external
llog <- 0
Fmargin <- matrix(nrow=N,ncol=I)
for(n in 1:N){
  for(i in 1:I){ 
    mm <- 0
    mmm <- 0
    for (m in 1:I){
      mm <- mm + B0[m] + B1[m]*x1[n] + B2[m]*x2[n]}
    mmm <- exp(mm - B0[i] - B1[i]*x1[n] - B2[i]*x2[n])
    Fmargin[n,i]<-(1/(1+exp((B0[i] + B1[i]*x1[n] + B2[i]*x2[n])- log10(mmm))))}}
  return(Fmargin)
}
B1 <- c(0,0.0167,0.0218,0.0286)
B2 <- c(0,0.339,0.653,-0.0442)
B0 <- c(2.35,0,0.352,-0.580)
iniFmargin<- Fmarginal(betas=c(B1,B2,B0))
#### G(y), gammas are the parameters to be estimated
Gmarginal <- function(gammas){
     N <- 4617 ## no of observations
     J <- 4 ## no of shipment size choices
     g1<-gammas[1:4]
     g2<-gammas[5:8]
     g0<-gammas[9:12]
     y1<-dist
     y2<-night
     llog <- 0
     Gmargin <- matrix(nrow=N,ncol=J)
     for(n in 1:N){
        for (j in 1:J){
           pp <- 0
           ppp <- 0
           for(p in 1:J){
              pp <- pp + g0[p] + g1[p]*y1[n] + g2[p]*y2[n]}
           ppp <- exp(pp - g0[j] - g1[j]*y1[n] - g2[j]*y2[n])
           Gmargin[n,j]<-(1/(1+exp((g0[j] + g1[j]*y1[n] + g2[j]*y2[n])- log10(ppp))))}}
      return(Gmargin)
  }

g1 <- c(0,1.97,2.23,1.29)
g2 <- c(0.15,0.22,0.32,0.65)
g0 <- c(2.76,0,-1.16,-3.12)
iniGmargin<- Gmarginal(gammas=c(g1,g2,g0))

#### Using RCopula
myCop <- archmCopula(param = 0.5, family="Frank", dim=2)
x <- cbind(iniFmargin,iniGmargin)
tau<-cor(x,method='kendall')[2]
fit.ml<-fitCopula(myCop,x,method="ml",lower=-Inf,upper=Inf, optim.method="Nelder-Mead",optim.control=list(maxit=10000),estimate.variance=FALSE)
loglikcop <- logLik(fit.ml)
stopifnot(all.equal(as.numeric(l),loglikCopula(coef(fit.ml),x=x,copula=myCop)))
```